# Azure AI/ML Prompt Flow deployment returning 403 when I send a request from Postman

Tags: azure, azure-promptflow

I am following the tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-studio/, specifically the part about deploying a prompt flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-studio/how-to/flow-deploy?tabs=azure-studio

I have created an AzureAI endpoint to test prompt flow deployment. When I send a request from Postman, I get `403` error

[image]

Why?

I am sending a `post` request to the endpoint which has endpoint's url, JSON body `{ "topic": "what is 2+2?}` and `api-key` authorisation - `key` = `api-key`, `value` = `value of the key`.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the JSON sample you have supplied is invalid (it's missing a quote mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You follow below steps.

Add below fields in **Headers** tab in postman.

**Authorization** - `Bearer <api_key>`

**azureml-model-deployment** - `<model_deployment_name>`

And make content type as `application/json`

[image]

Give input json like below.

```
{
    "chat_history":[],
    "question":["what is 20/4?"]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks. I didn't have to change the body though. Where are these steps documented?

Comment: Actually I got this in **consume** tab in deployments which is given in python.